# type 'List<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'Widget'

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to map List to Widget, but fail to do so.

```
 TableRow(children: [
                              item['questions'].map((item) {
                                return Column(
                                  children: [
                                    Text(item['name']),
                                    Checkbox(
                                        onChanged: _onRememberMeChanged,
                                        value: rememberMe),
                                  ],
                                );
                              }).toList()
                            ])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The TableRow gives a list of widgets, but you added a list inside of the list. You should extract the child list with 3 dots.

Try this

```
 TableRow(children: [
                              ...item['questions'].map((item) {
                                return Column(
                                  children: [
                                    Text(item['name']),
                                    Checkbox(
                                        onChanged: _onRememberMeChanged,
                                        value: rememberMe),
                                  ],
                                );
                              }).toList()
                            ])
```